# iTunes API: get 100x100 px icon of an App

Tags: json, app-store

I'm using iTunes API to get some informations about apps in App Store.

Reading the [documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) I saw that "artworkUrl100" parameter, taken from JSON request, will get me a 100x100 icon of the app.

I notice that this not works always, and sometimes it contains the url of a biggest icon.

Is there a way to get with certainty this icon (100x100 px)?

Comment: The 75,65,50 part is about the quality of the icon.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that like this.
Let say this is your link:
http://a223.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Purple/e0/ed/59/mzi.qaoavtgs.png

(from "artworkUrl512").

You just have to add *.100x100-75* before *.png* like this
http://a223.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Purple/e0/ed/59/mzi.qaoavtgs**.100x100-75**.png

Also ju can adjust icon size you need by adding different values like .150x150-75. Only problem is that this *-75* part depends on icon size. it can also be *-50* for smaller or *-65* for middle size icons. I still did not figure that out.

Hope this helps you.

EDIT:
You do not have to worry about .jpg or .jpeg. You can replace all with .png it will work.

Comment: Have you or has anybody found out how exactly to determine that part?

Comment: I think it is DPI, but I am not sure

Comment: This option is no longer 100% garantueed to work, ie: http://a420.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/44/46/2f/44462f9a-0b1e-4713-799c-b6aba6cbfbcb/mzl.btczfoqy.jpg

Comment: Hi, it seems that this way is no longer valid for all the apps... Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I have also encountered a few recent or semi-recent apps that this no longer works for (I use it for my portfolio, have a look at http://jonnystuffs.appspot.com/portfolio - some icons fail to load for this error). Some of them seem to have "normal" artwork512url:s, and one of them looks like pr_source.png?downloadKey=xxxxxxxx (long string). If doing the .100x100-75 or something else as described above, a **404 error** is returned.

Comment: Posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666002/itunes-api-artwork512url-method-of-getting-different-icon-sizes-no-longer-work