# Get retina scaled icons from iTunes search API

Tags: ios, scale, itunes, retina

I'm pulling live icons in iTunes Appstore from the iTunes api:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searchexamples

Like this

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?country=JP&id=288210303

Down the json, there is this entry:

"artworkUrl60": "http://a689.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/e0/1e/4f/e01e4ff0-05dd-165a-534b-6de08c99a6b4/icon.png",

This image turns out to be a 57x57 pixel icon. Not enough for retina screens. How can I get other scales of the artwork? I don't think I'm supposed to get 1024x1024px versions and scale them down right?

So, I'm hoping to get 60x60 point scale 2 most of the time, ie 120x120 pixels. And for our iOS6 friends 57x57 points/114x114 pixels.

Comment: OK this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171848/itunes-api-get-100x100-px-icon-of-an-app Maybe I could just get 100x100 and change my layout to use 50x50 points.

Comment: Ok this seems broken recently, I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666002/itunes-api-artwork512url-method-of-getting-different-icon-sizes-no-longer-work